# pheanstalk:put will be blocking when reserve() is blocking

Tags: beanstalkd, pheanstalk

I am so confused why put will be blocking when reserve() is blocking in pheanstalk, I have write two function:

1. put function :

[image]

2. worker function:

[image]

both of these are on a same host, but when i exec the function run(), if it's blocking; the function put() will blocking too, I am so confused.

Comment: oh, I have found the result that cause by session blocking.

Comment: If you ask a question and you find a solution by your self. It is great to share the solution with others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

er, because the cron job write after the session instance; and session add a file lock.